# Better truncate a CMAC from MSB or LSB

Tags: aes, mac

I want to truncate an AES128-CMAC from 16 down to 8 bytes length.
Citing [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493), "[...] It is possible to truncate the MAC. The result of the truncation should be taken in most significant bits first order. [...]".

When using [CryptoJS](http://artjomb.github.io/cryptojs-extension/) to generate such a CMAC over "Hello World" using the key "0xDEADBEEF CAFEBABE DEADBEEF CAFEBABE", this yields: **0x2425a8ff 14cea36d 0a14b3e8 3dbfc68e**.

1. I am not sure, whether my truncated CMAC according to the afore-mentioned definition is either *0x2425a8ff 14cea36d* **or** *0x0a14b3e8 3dbfc68e*.
   Or in other words: Is 0x24 of the CMAC the most- or least-significant-byte?
2. How does it affect security when taking the *wrong* 8 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

> ***Q1.*** I am not sure, whether my truncated CMAC according to the afore-mentioned definition is either `0x2425a8ff 14cea36d` or `0x0a14b3e8 3dbfc68e`. Or in other words: Is `0x24` of the CMAC the most- or least-significant-byte?

The RFC you mention has this:

> ```
> MSB(x)         The most-significant bit of the string x.
>                MSB(10010000) means 1
> ```

That means that the *leftmost* bytes contain the most significant bits (MSB means most significant bit). This is called *big endian* or *network byte order*. In other words, 0x24 is the most significant byte. It is quite common to take the leftmost / most significant bytes.

> ***Q2.*** How does it affect security when taking the wrong 8 bytes?

Not at all, but it may hurt interoperability. Either bit is as significant as the other; you might skip all the even or odd bits and have a secure MAC, as long as you decide which bits you use *up front*.

Answer (score 1):

Since 8 is half of 16, there are alternative solutions whereby you use both upper and lower bytes but still get 8 bytes out.

1. XOR adjacent pairs of bytes.
2. Fold the MAC, XORing 1st and 9th bytes etc.

These techniques are good for when you just can't decide which byte you like best and only take a few lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

Which part you take does not influence security.

I assume the reason that they state you should use the MSBs is that this was derived from a [NIST document.](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38b.pdf) NIST is a standards organization and if you want interoperability people need to use the same bits.

I don't know what CryptoJS does.